# Replace value in variable on click Reach JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, axios, es6-promise

I'm making a random movie generator using thmdb api. When sorting by genre, the api takes a string of all genre id's to exclude so it returns the results for the genre we want to search for. I'm using axios to make the http get request.

I've been able return the result once, however if the user decides to select another genre instead, it stacks the new string on top of the old one.

My obstacle is instead of stacking the new string on the existing, I want it to replace the content in the variable after each click. Any advice?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

`import axios from 'axios';`

```
import './genres.css';

class genres extends Component {
state = {
    title: [],
    genres: []
}

async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=34651b29c2c31f97c875d1f83f8f1d6d&language=en-US');
    this.setState({genres: response.data.genres});
    console.log(this.state.genres);
}

render() {
    const genres = this.state.genres.map(genre => {
        return <option key={genre.id} value={genre.id}>{genre.name}</option>
    })
    let sel = document.getElementById('genre_selector')


    let opt = ''
    let array = this.state.genres
    let index = []
    let selOpt = ''
    let toRemove = ''
    let genreFilter = ''

    const genreClickHandler = () => {
        opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex]
        selOpt = Number(opt.value)

        for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            index.push(this.state.genres[i].id)
        }

        toRemove = index.indexOf(selOpt)
        index.splice(toRemove, 1)
        index.join('%')
        genreFilter = index.join('%').toString()

        console.log(genreFilter)            
    }

    const selector = <select 
                        onClick={genreClickHandler} className="custom-select" id="genre_selector">

                            <option>Genres...</option>
                                    {genres}
                    </select>

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {selector}
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default genres;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a working example of this on codesandbox for you. I hope this helps. Good luck with your app!

The select takes an onChange and not a onClick.

https://codesandbox.io/s/w25zwnnw8l

Here is the documentation on React Selects!

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Hi Josh, thank you for taking the time to write that up for me! I'm still stuck though. If I select "Animation" (it's id is 16) when I console.log(genreFilter)  is:
28%12%35%80%99%18%10751%14%36%27%10402%9648%10749%878%10770%53%10752%37

Which is what I want (no number 16). However, let's say someone changes their mind to a different genre "Drama" for example, this happens:

28%12%16%80%99%10751%14%36%27%10402%9648%10749%878%10770%53%10752%37%28%12%16%35%80%99%18%10751%14%36%27%10402%9648%10749%878%10770%53%10752%37

It stacks the output instead of replacing it. Any thoughts on this?